# Disable autocomplete on Ext.form.ComboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How do i  disable autocomplete on Ext.form.ComboBox?
When the user type, i want the combobox to perform like a normal textbox.

I tried these settings but autocomplete still popping up.

```
  this.searchFieldBox = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        triggerAction: 'all',
        disableKeyFilter: true,
        store: this.searchStore,
        displayField: 'Value',
        autoSelect: false,
        fieldLabel: htmlHelpObject(me.id, this.Name),
        labelSeparator: '',
        labelCls: 'sectionLabel2',
        emptyText: 'Enter a search term',
        width: 500,
        labelWidth: 160,
        margin: "0 2 0 0",
        validateOnBlur: false,
        validateOnChange: false,
```

Comment: Settings minChers to a large number works but i don't like this hack.

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: The user does not like it. Any idea if it is possible?

Comment: Then why do you want to use  a combobox, From what I've seen it is not possible

Comment: If you want help it is not useful to downvote a answer if it is possible that your question didn't made it clear and without giving the answerer a chance to update the answer. There is a solution for this but I think you will find it yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is not that hard. `typeAhead` need to be off.

```
typeAhead: false
```

See this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKSGG/)** example for on/off

Comment: I want the whole dropdown thing to disappear. This won't accompish that.

Comment: @overule Thanks for the downvote. See my comment to your post